# Cefglue, ChromiumEmbeddedFramework and PDF

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefglue

currently I use Cefglue but I need to show PDF files, is it possible to add a plugin?
I read about pdf.js but how can I use it here?

Comment: Hi Sebastian,  I'm looking into whether CEF would be a good fit for an application I'm designing. Do you have any code or comments you could share? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New versions of CEF are already bundled with pdf plugin.

So you probably want to migrate to new CEF & CefGlue. At this moment supported version is 3.2171.1875.